# Already created virtualenv is not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created dato-env last night using general process of creating virtualenv and i installed some python packages like numpy , pandas, scikit learn Then i forgot to deactivate dato-env now i trying the command

```
source virt_env/dato-env/bin/activate
```

Then i am getting the below error

```
Error: no environment provided.
```

Can any one help me out of this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the file `virt_env/dato-env` still exist?

Comment: yeah i can see data-env.

Comment: No i am in my home directory only , any how i tried but not use.

Comment: Yesterday i forgot to deactivate dato-env may be this the reason.

Comment: data-env or dato-env?

Comment: activate/deactivate only sets PATH and ENV

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup it is dato-env only . Then how can we solve this problem (Thanks)

Comment: Do You have installed "anaconda"? An error message indicates that.

Comment: yeah i installed anaconda but  i do not  installed it in virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

I guess You have virtualenv in virtualenv. If its true, then

```
. virt_env/bin/activate
. virt_env/dato-env/bin/activate
```